# WebSQL | SQLite - Inserting the "?" character into the database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-sql

I'm attempting to insert a question into a database, however having some issues due to the prepared statement nature. The error is as follows:

```
could not prepare statement (1 near ")": syntax error)
```

here is the code being used:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO premade_questions ('Do you like animals?')", 
            [], 
            function() { console.log("Inserted"); },
            function(n, error) { console.log(error.message);    }
        );
```

When I change the code to use the preparred statement the error changes to this:

```
could not prepare statement (1 near "?": syntax error)
```

The changed code is as so:

```
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO premade_questions (?)", 
            ['Do you like animals?'], 
            function() { console.log("Inserted"); },
            function(n, error) { console.log(error.message);    }
        );
```

I've tried escaping the `?` however had no luck.

Comment: The command is `INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values)` so in your second version I think you want `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO premade_questions (yourfieldname) VALUES(?)", ` where `yourfieldname` is the name of the field holding the question.  (If you saw my earlier comment, I was talking rubbish - sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `VALUES` keyword:

If you table only contains the question text field, you should change your query to `INSERT INTO premade_questions VALUES ('Do you like animals?')`

If you have more fields, then you should either add them to the values, or specify that you're only supplying the question field. For example, if the field name is `question`, your query should then be: `INSERT INTO premade_questions (question) VALUES ('Do you like animals?')`.